# VSCode TreeItem select

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-tasks

I have a new TreeItem,on explorer view. How can I change items status when I click it. And I want to choose multiple items,when I press shift and click item at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible with VS Code, yet.

Please check the following link and put a `thumbs up` reaction to the top comment, so that it will get more consideration from the VSCode developers :)

[VSCode Github - Implement multi-select in left-panel file tree](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/1023)